# Green text "Profile" appears on login? (OSX Yosemite)

Tags: macos, login

Whenever I login to my machine some green text appears in the top left saying "Profile".
It has done this since OSX Mavericks too.

Here's a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Very weird -- I've never seen this before. This was the only thing I could find about it with Google: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1511640

Comment: Yeah, I saw this. I can't figure out why...
I'll create a new blank user and see if it happens there. Maybe, it's something I've installed.

Comment: I created a new user, and it doesn't appear. Meaning it's been run by a program I've installed. However, I have removed everything from my startup list...

Comment: Also check for anything strange in `~/Library/LaunchAgents`, or failing all else, take a look at all your processes with ``ps -U `whoami` ``

Comment: you've got mouse or sth from razer, right? :)

Comment: I do. I have a Razor Onza.
I don't think I've install it after I re-installed Yosemite on my Mac.

Comment: I recently bought a razer mouse and keyboard and this has appeared since installing the software for those products.

Comment: Seems like that could be the problem then.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This happens because of [Razr's mouse and keyboard software](http://www.razerzone.com/synapse/) that allows you to designate profiles for key bindings. The profile that is being used is displayed in green text in the corner of the screen on when logging in.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely [Razer's Synapse](http://www.razerzone.com/synapse/) software telling you which profile is currently active, as it starts on login, it pop's up on login. It also shows up on profile changes e.g. when you have profiles for different applications, it pops up every time you change to those applications.
Very annoying behaviour and I'd love to find a way to disable that crap (maybe an empty name works, otherwise there's always Controller Mate)

Comment: It definitely was Razer's software. Thanks to their build quality I now don't own any Razer mice.

Answer (score -1):

That looks like it may be coming from your monitor and not Mac OS.  It's possible that when you login a change in the display settings is triggering your monitor to change "profiles".

I would look through your monitor settings using the buttons on the monitor itself.

Comment: I would never have thought of this. To resolve my issue, I actually re-installed OSX (which worked).
I'd would've loved to have known if this was the cause.

Comment: I don't believe the monitor's OSD will appear in screenshots as is attached in the OP. Screenshots are typically converted from the framebuffer, which is from the computer, before anything can be overlaid onto the current frame.